# How do I specify more than one delimiter for cin.ignore() in C++?

Tags: c++, delimiter, cin, istream

The following is my code:

```
// Program to print the initials of a name
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  char first, last;
  cout<<"Enter first and last name: ";
  first = cin.get();
  cin.ignore(10000,' ');
  last = cin.get();
  cout<<first<<" "<<last;
  return 0;
}
```

I was looking for a way to specify more than one delimiter as the second parameter of `cin.ignore()`, e.g. `cin.ignore(10000,'\n' or ' ')`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: There is a simpler method to print the initals: `std::string first, last; std::cin >> first >> last; std::cout << first[0] << ' ' << last[0];`

Comment: @molbdnilo that's exactly what I'm trying to replicate using cin.ignore()

Comment: @AryanParekh same as what molbdnilo just explained

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is just to `peek()` the next character, check if it's in the list of delimiters, and if not then ignore it:

```
while (std::cin.peek() != '\n' && std::cin.peek() != ' ' && !std::cin.eof())
    std::cin.ignore(1);
```

Or:

```
char delim[] = { ' ', '\n' };
int delim_len = sizeof(delim) / sizeof(char);
while( std::find(delim, delim+delim_len, std::cin.peek()) == delim+delim_len) && !std::cin.eof() )
    std::cin.ignore(1);
```

From [cplusplus.com](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/peek/):

> `int peek();`
>
> Peek next character.
>
> Returns the next character in the input sequence, without extracting it: The character is left as the next character to be extracted from the stream.
>
> If any internal state flags is already set before the call or is set during the call, the function returns the end-of-file value (EOF).

Note: from the [`std::istream::ignore`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) reference, also on cplusplus.com,
we can see that only providing one parameter sets the `ignore()` delimiter to EOF by default:

```
istream& ignore (streamsize n = 1, int delim = EOF);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`std::any_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) to read until the read character is *any of* a set of characters that you define yourself.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm> // any_of
#include <iterator>  // istreambuf_iterator
#include <string>

std::istream& myignore(std::istream& is, const std::string& delims) {
    if(std::any_of(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is),
                   std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{},
                   [&delims](char ch){
                       return delims.find(ch) != std::string::npos;
                   }
    )) is.get(); // read the delimiter to remove it
    return is;
}
```

Then instead of calling `cin.ignore(10000, ' ')`, you call `myignore(cin, " \n");`

Comment: Thank you! Though, I'll have look further into the implementation to understand the terminology better

Comment: @Anjishnu You're welcome and please ask if you need any clarification.